# How do I reduce the number of 301 redirect entries using wildcards and variables in Squarespace?

Tags: redirect, wildcard, squarespace

I recently renamed all of the URLs that make up my blog... and have written redirects for almost every page... using wildcards where I can... keeping in mind... all that I know is the * wildcard at this time...

Here is an example of what I have...

```
/season-1/2017/1/1/snl-s01e01-host-george-carlin -> /season-1/snl-s01e01-george-carlin 301
```

I want to write a catch-all that will redirect all 38 seasons of reviews with one redirect entry... but I can't figure out how to get rid of just the word "host" between s01e01- and -george-carlin... and was thinking it would work something like this...

```
 /season-*/*/*/*/snl-s*e*-host-*-* -> /season-*/snl-s*e*[code to remove the word "host"]-*-* 301
```

Is that even close to being correct? Do I need that many *s

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to reduce the number of individual redirect entries using the [redirect features that Squarespace has to offer](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815308-URL-redirects), namely the wildcard (`*`) and a single variable (`[name]`). Multiple variables would be needed, but only `[name]` is supported.

The closest you can get is:
`/season-1/*/*/*/snl-s01e01-host-[name] -> /season-1/snl-s01e01-[name] 301`

But, if I'm understanding things, while the above redirect appears more general, it would still need to be copy/pasted for each post individually. So although it demonstrates the best that could be achieved, it is not a technical improvement.

Therefore, there are only two alternatives:

1. Create a Google Sheet (or other spreadsheet) where the old URLs are copy/pasted in column one, a formula using `arrayformula` and regular expressions to parse the old URL and generate the new URL is added in column two, and in column three a formula is written to `join` the two cells with `->` and `301`. With that done, you could click, drag and highlight all cells in column 3, copy, and paste them in the "URL Shortcuts" text area in Squarespace.
   It can be quite time consuming to figure out, write and test the correct formula, but it does avoid having to manually type out every redirect. Whether it is less time/effort in total depends on the number of redirects and one's proficiency with writing spreadsheet formulas.
   It could be that using the redirect code above would simplify the formula that'd need to be written in the spreadsheet, which may save some time.
2. Another alternative would be to remove your redirects and instead handle the redirect via JavaScript added to the 404/Page-not-found page. Because it sounds like you already have all of the redirects in place but are simply trying to reduce the overall number, I wouldn't recommend changing to a JavaScript-based approach. There are other drawbacks to using JavaScript, in any case.

Comment: Okay... thanks for this information... so if I were to write a catch-all redirect it still counts as the number of URLs caught by the code and not how many redirects you actually write.... when it comes to the suggestion to try to keep your redirect count low... I've already written a redirect for every URL I changed... I'm just trying to streamline things after the fact... pointing out the [name] approach will help me moving forward!!!

Comment: Thanks... these URLs are from old posts from when the blog was just a hobby... I may just have to live with what I have... which isn't all that bad... I haven't seen the issue really affect my page other than a few dings from SEO analytic tools... I'm trying more to meet these tools' needs than actually solve a problem... but... this is useful information going forward!!!

Comment: Cool... I'm apparently too new for my upvote to register yet... when I tried it told me I needed at least a user score of 15 points for it to show... but it's been clicked on the upvote button...